# When is the first time the TARDIS moves by itself (instead of "fading out"/"fading in")

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

In Classic *Doctor Who*, most often the TARDIS fades from view in one location and fades into view somewhere/somewhen else (often an area resembling a quarry). In the modern era, the TARDIS is more versatile, flying (literally) while in one time zone (as in "The Runaway Bride" when the TARDIS chases a taxi). What is the first time the TARDIS does something like that? Have I forgotten some example from Classic Who?

(note: I've added "by itself" to the title - I remember that the TARDIS has been moved by other people occasionally (or shoved down a mine shaft) - but those don't count)

Comment: Does this question include the Pertwee episodes where the Tardis Console was separate from the Tardis itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the first story in which the Tardis is shown flying in the air was the Second Doctor story [Fury from the Deep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fury_from_the_Deep).  This story opens with the Tardis descending through the sky before (crash?) landing into the ocean.

The BBC had rented a helicopter for the story (which is set around oil rigs being menaced by an underwater weed monster).  As described [here](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Fury_from_the_Deep_(TV_story)#Story_notes) the effect of the flying Tardis was achieved by suspending a model Tardis from the helicopter and flying it into the water.

Unfortunately this is one of the lost stories.  I found a reconstruction of the story [on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/FuryFromTheDeep/Fury+from+the+Deep+(1).mp4) but it is not the original.  I think it was made by stringing together still photos from the original.

Numerous stories feature the Tardis flying, rotating, through a star scape, and I would not be surprised if that happened before Fury from the Deep.

Comment: I don't know if falling into the ocean after materializing at some height counts as moving under its own power.

Comment: You beat me to it.  A note, although Fury is missing, the clip of the TARDIS landing was reused in The War Games, so it survives.

Comment: I'm going to accept it - thanks